# How to solve the task called 'Fast and Furious' from 'Break In 2017' challenge in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, session, cookies, httpwebrequest

I try to solve the task called [Fast and Furious](https://felicity.iiit.ac.in/contest/breakin/question/1/4/) from [Break In 2017](https://felicity.iiit.ac.in/contest/breakin/) challenge.

The task is simple. Need to HTTP post back the result of a math expression contained in a HTML page. It can be achieved by this python script:

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://felicity.iiit.ac.in/contest/extra/fastandfurious/'
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url)
print(r.text)
m = re.search('\(.*\)', r.text)
while m:
    ans = eval(m[0])
    print(m[0] + ' -> ' + str(ans))
    r = s.post(url, data={'ques_ans' : ans})
    print(r.text)
    if ('the_flag_is_' in r.text): break
    m = re.search('\(.*\)', r.text)
```

I want to do the same in C#. I tried like this:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

    static HttpWebRequest Create(string url)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.UserAgent = "dummy";
        return request;
    }

    static string Get(string url)
    {
        var request = Create(url);
        request.Method = "GET";

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    static string Post(string url, string postData)
    {
        var request = Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

    static string Eval(string expression)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        return dt.Compute(expression, "").ToString();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string url = "https://felicity.iiit.ac.in/contest/extra/fastandfurious";
        string text = Get(url);
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        var m = Regex.Match(text, @"\(.*\)");

        while (m.Success)
        {
            var ans = Eval(m.Value);
            Console.WriteLine(m.Value + " -> " + ans);
            text = Post(url, "ques_ans=" + ans);
            Console.WriteLine(text);
            if (text.Contains("the_flag_is_")) break;
            m = Regex.Match(text, @"\(.*\)");
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not work, because I always get back the 'Level 1' question. I used HttpWebRequest.CookieContainer property to reuse the cookies across different requests to keep up a session.

I don't know what is the problem. Maybe the session doesn't work.
Or perhaps HttpWebRequest is too slow to post back the result in time.

How to solve this automation task in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't handling being redirected.  Watching the traffic we can see that this particular server would like your requests to /fastandfurious to end with a trailing slash.  so change '../fastandfurious' to '../fastandfurious/' and that will fix it.

Comment: I didn't notice the missing trailing slash. This solves the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just for my curiosity I tried python script with the wrong url, and it worked well (it handles redirection well). In C# for HttpWebRequest the AllowAutoRedirect property is true by default, but it still does not work with the wrong url. MSDN doesn't say anything about it, but is it possible that AllowAutoRedirection doesn't work together with CookieContainer?